# HTML Form Create More inputs based off of answer to questions

Tags: php, html

```
<form method="post" action="" >
<input type ="text" placeholder="Test Name" name="name">
<input type="number" placeholder="Number Of Questions" name ="numb">
<input type="submit" value="Start">
</form>
```

My code so far is above. What I want is whatever number of questions is, I want it to create is

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Question + Numb">
    <select name="numbOptions" placeholder="Number of Options For question + numb">
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Two</option>
        <option value="3">Three</option>
        <option value="4">Four</option>
        <option value="5">Five</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Option1">
```

For each question and I am unsure as of how to create more inputs within the form based off of what the input is for number of questions. Also I will have to keep track of which is which as this as a php form. Also as guessed I will use it for options below, whatever the solution may be but I plan to be able to recreate that myself. Thanks for any assistance or guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `for` loop to achieve this.

```
<select name="numbOptions" placeholder="Number of Options For question + numb">
<?php
  for ($i = 0; $i < $_POST['numb']; $i++) {
    echo "<option value='" . $i . "'>" . $i . "</option>";
  }
?>
</select>
```

**Update:**
*to automatically change it, you'd have to use some JavaScript (I'm using jQuery, but this is all possible with vanilla JavaScript as well)*

First give an id to the number input, I'm going to give it the id of `numb`

```
<input type="number" placeholder="Number Of Questions" name="numb" id="numb">
```

And give an id to the empty select, I'm naming it `numb-options`

```
<select name="numbOptions" placeholder="Number of Options For question + numb" id="numb-options">
```

Now we're going to have this at the bottom of the page in `<script>` tags right before the closing `<body>` tag:

```
$("#numb").change(function(){
    $.ajax({url: "load-question.php", success: function(result){
        $("#numb-options").html(result);
    }});
});
```

What does that do?! Ajax allows you load another php script (in this case, named `load-question.php`), and append its output inside of another element (in this case, the select element)

So now we're going to move the original code from before this update, into a new file called `load-question.php`

<sub><sup>**Note:** This is untested, do follow up if you have any issues, and you will need jquery for it to work</sup></sub>

Comment: That works for original creation but how do I modify when they decide for more options. So automatically after they change the result in that input

Comment: That would be a bit more tricky, you'd have to use ajax for that. Are you using jQuery in this project?

Comment: @TomBraccia I have updated the answer, should be able to do what you want ;)

Comment: Thank you so much, so my question with this would be as to whether or not it will be able to load the questions directly below.

Comment: @TomBraccia yes it would, you'd have to create another ajax for creating the questions too, I'll let you figure that out, shouldn't be too much different from the example I gave you ;)